# Finding my own harmonic oscillator (differential equations assignment)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

In my intro to differential equations class, we were assigned a project from the textbook in which we are to find out own harmonic oscillator. Here are some details:

" In the text, we claim that the harmonic oscillator can be used as a simple model for many different situations. The key ingredients are a **restoring force**, which pushes the system back toward a rest position, and (perhaps) a **damping force**.

For this lab, you are to find such a system. It may be mechanical, biological, psychological, political, financial, or whatever. You will have to do some analysis on your system, so you will need to be able to **obtain some data** on its “motion.” You can either record the data yourself or use published data (with proper references). "

The report should include a **second-order differential equation** and/or a **system of differential equations**, as well as a **direction field** and/or **phase plane**.

I need help finding good real life examples of systems with the properties mentioned above. But mainly, I need help finding actual data from online sources that I can use for this project. And it must be something other than your classic spring-mass system.

Thank you!

Comment: @Moo Thank you! And yeah using circuit emulator might work, do you have any ones that you recommend?

Comment: Check [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6767/where-can-i-find-biological-time-series-data) out. Predator-prey is amazing.